# using private method from base in friend sub class -- compiler bug in NVCC?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

While trying to compile some CUDA code using Intel Threading Building Blocks, I discovered what I think is a bug in `nvcc`. The following minimal example compiles fine using `g++` 5.4:

```
class Sub;
class Other;

namespace internal {
  class Base
  {
  private:
    friend class ::Sub;

    static void foo(::Sub& b);
    static void foo(::Other& c);
  };
}

class Sub : private internal::Base
{
public:
  using internal::Base::foo;
};

void internal::Base::foo(Sub& b)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Sub *b;
  b->foo(*b);
  // Sub::foo(*b);

  return 0;
}
```

But if I compile it with `nvcc` 8.0 combined with the same host compiler, using

```
nvcc -x cu -arch=sm_35 -c minimal.cc
```

I get the following interesting error:

```
../minimal.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../minimal.cc:28:21: error: ‘internal::Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Sub’
```

A somewhat more descriptive error is obtained if `Base` is moved out of the `internal` namespace and into to global namespace:

```
../minimal.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../minimal.cc:6:12: error: ‘class Base Base::Base’ is inaccessible
   class Base
            ^
../minimal.cc:32:5: error: within this context
   b->foo(*b);
     ^
../minimal.cc:32:11: error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Sub’
   b->foo(*b);
```

Clearly, this seem to be due to the somewhat non-standard way of calling the static method using a pointer, and if that row is replaced by the one commented out, it compiles just fine.

Can someone confirm if this is valid C++ and thus a bug in `nvcc`, or invalid C++ that `g++` somehow still happily accepts?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The code you posted compiles perfectly for me. However, the error message you showed wasn't produced by compiling the code you posted, so there might be discrepancies which I cannot account for. Can you update the question with the exact code, compile command, and error message?

Comment: @talonmies, the exact code is given, the exact error message is also given, and the exact compilation command is `nvcc -c -arch=sm_35 file.cu`. As stated, I have nvcc 8.0 and g++ 5.4. I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The error you have shown is reported on line 31. That is `return 0` in the code you posted. And in your question you show the error being reported in a file with a `.cc`  file extension and the compile command you just posted in comments is compiling a file with a `.cu` extension. nvcc handles those two cases differently. As I said, you haven't shown code and error which match and which I can reproduce.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for pointing out the non-consistent error message. I've updated it now. I also added the command for compiling the same file with `nvcc`. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I've reported this internally to the NVIDIA compiler team.

Comment: Similar or same issue, no solution posted there: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/881443/nvcc-and-nested-class-issue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug some more into this, and saw that it indeed is a problem with one of the phases of the `nvcc` compilation. Using `--save-temps`, and checking out the resulting `.cu.cpp.ii` file, it turns out that this line

```
b->foo(*b);
```

gets substituted by the following

```
(b->internal::Base::foo(*b));
```

This does not compile with `g++`, since then the fact that `foo` is exported as public in `Sub` is lost. After all, this tries to explicitly access it from the base class where it is `private`. Using the other type of invocation (`Sub::foo`) does not result in any extra code being generated.

I conclude that this is an bug in `nvcc`. It is interesting that this substitution does *not* happen if the second overloaded  `void foo(::Other &c)` is not declared in `Base`.